# .net using sockets to communicate

Tags: vb.net

I use this code to send the message through socket

```
  Public Shared Function sendMessage(messageBytes As Byte()) As Byte()
        Const bytesize As Integer = 1024 * 1024
        Try
            Dim client As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8888)
            ' Create a new connection
            Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

            stream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length)

            messageBytes = New Byte(bytesize - 1) {}

            stream.Read(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length)

            ' Clean up
            stream.Dispose()
            client.Close()
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try

        Return messageBytes
    End Function
```

And this one should receive the sent message but for some reason it wont

Server code

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim client As New TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8888)
    Dim socket As Socket = client.Client


    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(1024) {}

    Try
        ' Receive data with timeout 10s  
        Receive(socket, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 10000)
        Dim str As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        MsgBox(str)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Debugger says the problem is on first line when i try to run it 
"{"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"}"

Comment: Server side should be using [`TcpListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx)?

Comment: Yeap that is it. Thanks a lot